# Cannot send a ber-tlv response with a length superior to 127

Tags: payment-processing, emv, tlv

I have a problem sending IAD format 2 with biometric authentication. I work with a payment terminal and he only accept my IAD when his size is under 23 bytes (like a format 1 IAD) and I don't find where I can specify the format version.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Visa online ( you need to have access ), download
Visa Contactless Payment Specification (VCPS)
Visa Supplemental Requirements

and refer section.
M Issuer Application Data (IAD) and Card Verification Results (CVR) Formats

Length of any TLV object is processed as per below rule.
[image]

Comment: I found out the problem, actually my transaction is blocked because my gpo response is too long. I can't send a response with more than 127 bytes. I don't understand where could I change the maximum length of the response or if I need to change something else.

Comment: Edited the answer, maybe that helps, or else I will delete the answer if no relevance.